# onclick not working for ui:outputcurrency

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I have code that iterates over a list. for some reason the onclick method does not seem to fire. Is there something wrong in my code below?
Also how can I get the index id of the clicked row ?`

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.txList}" var="tl" indexVar="index">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="slds-truncate"  >{!tl.dateCreatedFormatted}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!tl.status == 'Sent'}">
            <ui:outputCurrency aura:id="{!index}"  class = "red" value="{!tl.amount}" click = "{!c.handleRowClick}"/>
        </aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!tl.status == 'Received'}">
            <ui:outputCurrency aura:id="{!index}"  class = "green" value="{!tl.amount}" click = "{!c.handleRowClick}"/>
        </aura:if>

    </td>

    <td>
        <div class="slds-truncate" >{!tl.transactionId}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="slds-truncate" >{!tl.status}</div>
    </td>

</tr>
```

Controller.js

```
handleRowClick: function(component, event, helper) { 
    console.log("Row clicked");     

},
```

Comment: can you add details of what you would like to do on `ui:outputCurrency` click?

Comment: Just a note: "Components in the ui namespace are deprecated as of API version 47.0, the Winter ’20 release. We recommend that you use components in the lightning namespace instead or use the Lightning web component equivalent. You can continue to use the ui components beyond Summer ’21 but Salesforce plans to cease support for them in Summer ’21. For more information, see Working with Base Lightning Components"

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ui_overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of small problems.

First, notably, aura:id does not support merge syntax, so you've literally named your elements `{!index}`. While you can use [aura:id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm) to find all the elements, it's not really necessary in this case, because we do happen to know which row was selected based on the `event.target`.

The relevant documentation for aura:id states:

> aura:id doesn't support expressions. You can only assign literal string values to aura:id.

Second, if you're really interested in capturing a click for the entire row, consider setting it on your `tr` element directly:

```
<tr onclick="{!c.handleRowClick}">
  <!-- omitted for brevity -->
</tr>
```

Of course, you could choose to attach the handler to each individual element, as in your example, but it won't handle clicks made in the whitespace that comprises the row around the elements.

The easiest way to identify your row is to use a dataset attribute somewhere:

```
<tr onclick="{!c.handleRowClick}" data-row-index="{!index}">
  <!-- omitted for brevity -->
</tr>
```

Which is accessed in your code as follows:

```
handleRowClick: function(component, event, handler) {
    var target = event.target;
    while(target && !target.dataset.rowIndex) {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if(target) {
        console.log(target.dataset.rowIndex);
    }
}
```

This code simply walks up the DOM hierarchy until it finds the element that has a rowIndex attribute.

If you're not familiar with dataset, make sure you read it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). The most important part to know is that hyphens, as demonstrated above, convert the next letter to uppercase, since we can't literally use a hyphen in a variable name.